# Show different bibtex field when writing in different languages

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, chinese

I write in English as well as Chinese. When I cite Chinese work in English paper, I want to include both the English transcription/translation and original Chinese characters. But when I cite Chinese work in Chinese paper, I don't need to include the transcription. Is there a possible and convenient way to switch from these two circumstances, provided I make only one bibtex record for each reference, instead of two (Chinese version .bib and English version)?

I use Biblatex + TeXlive2018 + Win10

**Example**

When I write in **English**, I want output be like this:
[image]

When I write in **Chinese**, I want the same two references be like this:
[image]

(`Biblatex-Chicago` style is used)

That is to say:

English reference in English/Chinese writing --> remains English

Chinese reference in English writing --> shows both English and Chinese fields

Chinese reference in Chinese writing --> shows Chinese fields only

Comment: At the moment that is not really possible without serious manual modifications to the style. A few years ago, there was an idea to implement a `multiscript` version of `biblatex` that would make these things easier (https://github.com/plk/biblatex/tree/ms, https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/416), but unfortunately development for that feature has stalled in recent years.

Answer (score 3):

This is a proof of concept of a limited alternative which, I'm sure, it won't take long before someone finds an unfixable flaw. But I submit it as an idea. As it stands, it only works for literal fields (I'm using `title` here as example) and I'm not sure if this could be extended for names and lists. It will very likely generate some problems with `biblatex`'s formatting directives. It is also a fragile setting, as we need to place some macros directly in the bibentry field of interest.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
  @book{book1,
    author = {Author},
    title = {\caseenglish{Title}\casebrazilian{Título}},
    date = {2000},
    location = {Location},
    publisher = {Publisher},
    addendum = {An entry in Brazilian Portuguese, for which we want both titles
      when the language is English and Portuguese title when the langage is
      brazilian},
  }

  @book{book2,
    author = {Author},
    title = {English title},
    date = {2004},
    location = {Location},
    publisher = {Publisher},
    addendum = {An entry in English, which should always be in English},
  }

\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{iflang}
\usepackage[brazilian,english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\newcommand*{\caseenglish}[1]{#1}
\newcommand*{\casebrazilian}[1]{#1}

\AtBeginBibliography{%
  \IfLanguageName{english}{%
    \renewcommand*{\casebrazilian}[1]{ #1}%
  }{}%
  \IfLanguageName{brazilian}{%
    \renewcommand*{\caseenglish}[1]{}%
  }{}%
}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}

\printbibliography

\selectlanguage{brazilian}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]